# PrimeFaces mega menu is hidden behind the centre contents, left & right side bars

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, megamenu

I'm displaying a [`<p:megaMenu>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/menubar.xhtml) on the header of template.

```
<p:layoutUnit id="topPanel" position="north" size="155" collapsed="false" resizable="false" closable="false" collapsible="false" gutter="6">

    <span style="position: absolute; top: 90px; width: 1360px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow-y: hidden;">

        <p:megaMenu>

        </p:megaMenu>

    </span>
</p:layoutUnit>
```

The `<p:megaMenu>` is the same as the one shown on the PrimeFaces showcase as indicated by the link shown (the default one).

It looks like the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2xJT.png).

[image]

When this menu is popup, it is hidden behind the content bar (`<p:layoutUnit position="center"...>` and the left side bar as can be seen in the snap shot).

I have tried with the following CSS class.

```css
#topPanel {z-index:2 !important; }
```

but to no avail.

How to fix this? How to show `<p:megaMenu>` over the content bar and left & right side bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following CSS classes need to be overridden.

```css
.ui-layout-north {
    z-index: 20 !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
}

.ui-layout-unit-content {
    overflow:visible !important;
}
```

---

Also in this particular case, the `style` attribute of the `<span>` tag as shown in the question needs to be modified as follows.

```
<span style="position: absolute; top:90px; width:1360px; left:0px; bottom:0px;">
```

Removing the `overflow-y: hidden;` attribute (unnecessary) or it won't work even though the above CSS classes have been overridden.